# Apple Pay with React Native

Tags: ios, react-native, stripe-payments, applepay

We are trying to add an Apple Pay button to our React Native App. Is it possible to create your own apple pay button in react native, or is it required you use some sort of API / kit / asset?

Comment: Did you succeed in implementing Apple Pay into your React Native app???

Comment: No, unfortunately i did not. The project was put on pause.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can create your own apple pay button. You just have to make sure to use their asset for the apple icon and follow their strict style guidelines.

You can find a lot of documentation here: https://www.apple.com/apple-pay/ and you can download the necessary asset here: https://images.apple.com/apple-pay/downloads/Apple_Pay_Payment_Mark.zip

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/Naturalclar/react-native-add-wallet This helped me create an **add to apple wallet button** in react-native app using native module.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).